# How to get redirects from pywikibot in python

Tags: python, pywikibot

I would like to know if `pywikibot` api allows to retrieve the redirects of a given wikipedia article.

I tried the following.

```
pw.Page(pw.Site('en'), 'forensics').showRedirects()
pw.Page(pw.Site('en'), 'forensics').redirects()
```

However, I got an error saying `AttributeError: 'Page' object has no attribute 'showRedirects'`

I am happy to provide more details if needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [backlinks](https://doc.wikimedia.org/pywikibot/master/api_ref/pywikibot.html#pywikibot.page.BasePage.backlinks):

```
page.backlinks(filter_redirects=True)
```

---

Side note: There is also [getReferences](https://doc.wikimedia.org/pywikibot/master/api_ref/pywikibot.html#pywikibot.page.BasePage.getReferences):

```
page.getReferences(filter_redirects=True)
```

but this is **not** the same as `backlinks`. `page.getReferences(filter_redirects=True)` returns pages that are

- redirects (but not necessary a redirect to the `page`)
- contain a reference to the `page`

This is rare, but happens. For example assuming that page A contains the following wikitext:

```
#Redirect[[C]]
{{B}}
```

This page will be returned by `Page(site, 'B').getReferences(filter_redirects=True)`, but not by `Page(site, 'B').backlinks(filter_redirects=True)`.